# Выполнение js на сайте при работающем касперском

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой после установки **Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2017**.
На сайте есть выпадающее меню, реализованное через **js**. Работает оно нормально, ошибок нет.
Но, после того, как я установил себе антивирусник, при заходе на главную страницу, где находится это меню, теперь пункты меню, у которых есть вложенные подпункты (они разворачивались при наведении), сразу представлены развернутыми.
В консоли разработчика через браузер наблюдаю ряд ошибок:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined -
>   jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:46 
>  Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   jQuery is not defined - index.html:1
>  Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   jQuery is not defined - jquery.mousewheel-.0.4.pack.js:14 
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined index.html:34
>  
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:95
>  
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:176 
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>    onmouseover @
>   index.html:269

Я так понимаю, что Касперский с клиентской стороны как-то нарушает работу **js**. Данная ошибка наблюдается во всех браузерах (IE, Mozilla, Chrome, Opera).

**Примечание:** добавление сайта в исключение веб-антивируса не помогает, потому что все работает нормально, только если полностью выключить KAV, если включить любую из функций в KAV'e, то ошибка возникает, вне зависимости какая защита (какой модуль) была включена.

Comment: Кажется он блочит jquery. Попробуйте соседние версии.

Comment: Все ли скрипты подгружены на сайт? Откуда берется скрипт, с Вашего сайта или CDN?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev необходимо настроить под эту версию, я же не смогу пользователям трактовать "отключение касперского" для работы с сайтом.

Comment: @MrFylypenko скрипты берутся с сайта

Comment: @Legionary, может червячек завелся в вашем jquery? Если всё чисто и точно правильный урл, то надо касперу писать, у них бывает такое

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev все чисто и урлы правильные, похоже правда нужно касперам писать, прочитал на одном из форумов, что в программу вшит какой то скрипт и он неотключаемый, он создает такую ошибку.